# SQL COUNT EXCLUDE

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, aggregate-functions

Hello here's my question 
Retrieve the total number of bookings for each type of the services that 
have at least three bookings (excluding those cancelled). 
i.e. where status = 'open' AND 'done'

I'm not to sure on how to exclude and how to count values in a column?

```
SELECT Service.type, Service.description,   
COUNT (DISTINCT status) 
FROM Booking
LEFT JOIN Service
ON Booking.service = Service.type
WHERE status >= 3
EXCLUDE 'cancelled'
GROUP BY status DESC;

CREATE TABLE Booking(
car         CHAR(8)                             ,
on_date     DATE                        NOT NULL,
at_time     TIME                        NOT NULL,
technician  CHAR(6)                     NOT NULL,
service     VARCHAR(15)                 NOT NULL,
status      VARCHAR(9)CHECK(status IN ('open','done', 'cancelled')) DEFAULT 'open'     NOT         NULL, 
note        VARCHAR(200)                            ,
rating      INTEGER CHECK(rating IN('0','1','2','3','4','5')) DEFAULT '0'   NOT NULL,
feedback    VARCHAR(2048)                           ,

PRIMARY KEY (car, on_date, at_time),

FOREIGN KEY (car) REFERENCES Car (cid)
                ON DELETE CASCADE   
                ON UPDATE CASCADE, 

FOREIGN KEY (technician) REFERENCES Technician (tech_id)
                ON DELETE CASCADE   
                ON UPDATE CASCADE, 

FOREIGN KEY (service) REFERENCES Service (type)
                ON DELETE CASCADE   
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Service(
type        VARCHAR(15)     PRIMARY KEY,
description VARCHAR(2048)   
);
```

Comment: Post the tables' structures. `\d booking`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be faster to aggregate first and join later. Fewer join operations. Hence the subquery:

```
SELECT s.type, s.description, b.ct
FROM  (
   SELECT service, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   booking
   WHERE  status <> 'cancelled'
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING count(*) > 2
   ) b
JOIN service s ON s.type = b.service;
```

Since you enforce referential integrity with a foreign key constraint and `service` is defined `NOT NULL`, you can as well use `[INNER] JOIN` instead of a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` *in this query*.

It would be cleaner and more efficient to use an [`enum`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-enum.html) data type instead of `VARCHAR(9)` for the `status` column. Then you wouldn't need the `CHECK` constraint either.

For best performance of this particular query, you could have a [partial covering index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) (which would also profit from the `enum` data type):

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON booking (service)
WHERE  status <> 'cancelled';
```

Every index carries a maintenance cost, so only keep this tailored index if it actually makes your query faster (test with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867836/poor-performance-on-a-postgresql-query/19460872#19460872)) and it is run often and / or important.

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.type, s.description, count(*) 
from
    booking b
    inner join
    service s on b.service = s.type
where status != 'cancelled'
group by 1, 2
having count(*) >= 3
order by 3 desc;
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You might get more upvotes that way!

Comment: @TheGuy Please check Erwin's answer. He just changed the only major difference in his query from `left` to `inner` join.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT Service.type, Service.description, COUNT (status) 
FROM Booking 
LEFT JOIN Service ON Booking.service = Service.type 
WHERE status != 'cancelled' 
GROUP BY Service.type, Service.description
HAVING COUNT(status) >= 2;
```

The service attributes have to be grouped as well.
Filtering by aggregate, here `COUNT(status)`, is what the `HAVING` clause does.