# Choose subset of rows grouped by part of a column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relational-database, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have these rows in a table:

```
ID | SomeColumn | SomeDateTime
---+------------+-------------
1  | X1         | 01-01-14 14:00:00
2  | X2         | 01-01-14 22:00:00
3  | Y1         | 01-03-14 12:00:00
4  | Y2         | 01-03-14 23:00:00
```

How could I make an SQL query to grab just the rows with **distinct** dates (choosing the latest times)? That is, the result of the query should be:

```
ID | SomeColumn | SomeDateTime
---+------------+-------------
2  | X2         | 01-01-14 22:00:00
4  | Y2         | 01-03-14 23:00:00
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT MAX(SomeDateTime),ID,SomeColumn,SomeDateTime
FROM MyTable GROUP BY (SomeDateTime::date)
```

The error I get is:

> ```
> The column "MyTable.ID" needs to appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregation function
> ```

I'm using PostgreSQL, but if you have answers for other DB engines, I'll upvote too.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (some_datetime::date)
       id, some_column, some_datetime
FROM   tbl 
ORDER  BY some_datetime::date, some_datetime DESC;
```

Detailed explanation for `DISTINCT ON`:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

The slightly special requirement here is to form partitions on a derived value. A cast to `date` is the simplest and fastest way.

Returns a single row per day (for days with any rows). If there are ties, an arbitrary row is picked, unless you add more `ORDER BY` items as tiebreaker.

Comment: thanks Erwin, I've also found another solution which I posted as another answer, do you see any disadvantages with it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a fairly readable solution (even if it's a query with a subquery, which might be less efficient than the proposed solutions):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SomeDateTime IN (
    SELECT MAX(SomeDateTime) FROM MyTable GROUP BY (SomeDateTime::date)
)
```

Comment: If `SomeDateTime` is not unique, there is a difference. While this one returns *all* rows matching the maximum timestamp per day, my solution returns a maximum of *one* row per day. Same difference as with [`row_number()` vs. `rank()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410315/how-to-select-more-than-1-record-per-day/13414130#13414130). It depends what you need exactly. To see which is faster just test with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867836/poor-performance-on-a-postgresql-query/19460872#19460872).